# Declare Inner Activity In The Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity

In my thread I create an inner activity 'B' at one point in order to launch another activity for result. I need to declare this  in my Android manifest file but can not work out what the name of it is as the standard ".B" does not work as it says that activity does not exist. How can I declare this activity?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried the name of the class 'A' prefixing it like '.A.B', and also the qualified name but because this includes the name of the thread variable, and a 'run()' command it is illegal.

Comment: are you using eclipse it can detect activities in your project for you you just select them to add it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As someone pointed out, in AndroidManifest, use the `$` sign, like:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".A$B">
   ```
2. Declare class `B` as static:

   ```
   public static class B
   ```

Comment: The "public static" modifiers are indeed important!

Answer (score 5):

To reference an inner class use the "$" instead of a dot.

```
.A$B
```

It may also be prefaced with the package path

```
com.yourcompany.projectname.A$B
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the reverse stuff, create the class as activity and do the thread as inner class.

Comment: Right, I've moved my inner class to the activity that stores a handler to the thread. Any reference to thread variables have to be removed because in order to declare the activity in the manifest it has to not only be public, but also static.