# Tag <action> attribute name has invalid character '$'

Tags: android, android-manifest

Android Studio gives me the upper error (see title) when defining a service like so:

```
<service
    android:name=".broadcast_receivers.SimpleWakefulReceiver$SimpleWakefulService"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".broadcast_receivers.SimpleWakefulReceiver$SimpleWakefulService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

However, Android Studio also autocomplete-suggests me this string for the name parameter.

I've declared `SimpleWakefulService` as a public static class:

```
public class SimpleWakefulReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("onReceive " + intent.getAction());
        [...]
    }

    public static class SimpleWakefulService extends IntentService {
        public SimpleWakefulService() {
            super("[...]");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

I've found other threads stating that '$' is the correct character in such cases:
[Cannot start service in inner class - is it my Android Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744881/cannot-start-service-in-inner-class-is-it-my-android-manifest)
[Declare Inner Activity In The Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687661/declare-inner-activity-in-the-android-manifest)

So is this a bug of Android Studio?

Comment: did you checked you have `SimpleWakefulService` inner class in your `SimpleWakefulReceiver`

Comment: Yes, of course I have... added it to the question now, though. However, Android Studio is complaining about the '$' character, nothing else.

Comment: `action` is not `name`. The fact that you have a static inner class requires a `$` in `android:name`. While I was not aware of any limits on the characters in an action string, there is no requirement that you have a `$` in the action string, just because you are implementing a static inner class.